# Google Tag Manager loads something over http instead https

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have implemented the Google Tag Manager script on my website just like they pointed in this tutorial [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart).

But they load something with `http` protocol instead of `https` which is causing the security on my website to fail (no padlock is showing).

[image: e]

Can I fix it, or is it Google's failure?

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Googles fault. The tag in your picture is not part of GTM.

Apparently ["exelator" is malware](https://howtoremove.guide/what-is-loadm-exelator-com-malware/) that tries to redirect your requests to unsafe websites (on order to steal your data). So this is something on your local system, you need to run an antivirus/anti-malware software to remove it.

Comment: Thank you! Culprit found.
Apparently the person who created this Google Tag had issues and malware on his PC which caused this.